# How secure is data sent Android from to Azure Cloud?

Tags: security, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am wondering if the channel used to transmit data to be sent to the Azure Cloud Mobile service is secured. Using the below code as reference..

```
table.execute(new TableQueryCallback<tableEntity>() {
        public void onCompleted(List<tableEntity> result, int count,
            Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                for (tableEntity tableItem: result) {
                    //Some algorithm here
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The code executes and attempts to retrieve data from  Azure, and I am not sure how secure this process is. Reading the documentations on Azure site, it did not provide the answer that I am looking for..

Reference I have read:

azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/

azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/

azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/

What I am looking for is how the process of sending/retrieving data to and from Azure works, am I needed to encrypt the data channel? Any guide will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services is a REST service hosted in the cloud. The client code is making HTTP calls to the REST API behind-the-scenes. So all encryption is done via HTTPS/SSL.

You can find REST API details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710108.aspx

If you wanted to, you could test your service by using PostMan/curl/Fiddler or any other HTTP client.

The AppKey is sent in the X-ZUMO-APPLICATION HTTP header along with your other requests and acts as a very simple authentication method and is used when you've set up your API/Table endpoint with 'Application Key' permissions.

Permission details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj193161.aspx

Comment: I would like to thank you so much. I had given up on getting an specific answer from a source that I could include in my justification. But just another question, considering the Request URL is using "https://<service_name>.azure-mobile.net/login/<provider>", can I assume that there are encryption involved already?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post if you haven't already: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/23/troubleshooting-authentication-issues-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx

Comment: ... continued from above:

That explains how the login flow works. All the login functionality is handled by the login provider (just as you'd log in to facebook/google from their own sites) and you are provided back with an encrypted token used to authenticate with your mobile service.

This also has some useful info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987682/how-do-you-securely-access-windows-azure-mobile-services-with-javascript-in-a-we

Comment: Hi brettsam, thanks for getting back to me. Now I understood how Azure actually work with an identity provider. I guess I missed this out.. What about on a case where I am not using any of the identity provider? I am using this right now 
MobileServiceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient("MobileServiceUrl", "AppKey");

Comment: does this mean we don't need to encrypt data before inserting into the azure storage? Cause all my clients are going to be interacting with the database but will be querying only data that belongs to them. Should I use encryption or can skip it if MobileServices is already secure?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a reliable source for this, but I'm under the impression that the `AppKey` is used to encrypt the data connection between the client and mobile service.

```
// Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
// Mobile Service URL and key
mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
        "MobileServiceUrl",
        "AppKey", 
        this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());
```

And of course you can set your table permissions to restrict access to any sensitive data. Obviously this is not enough if you are working with something that you seriously need to encrypt and keep safe.

Comment: Somehow along the line of what I had in mind! I am thankful for your advice!